# how can I display data from database to sb-admin template?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in laravel and sb-admin template. I do hope someone can help me with my problem. I want to display in a select tag the data from my database table, but it's only showing this error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: kras (View: C:\Users\ICTOffice\Desktop\sbmMea\resources\views\admin\AIPcreate.blade.php)

this is my Kra model code

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kra extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['id',`KRADetail`];


}
```

the Krascontroller contains,

```
  public function index()
    {
        $kras=Kras::all();
        return view('admin.AIPcreate',compact('kras'));
    }
```

on my blade file, i use this code to display the data
AIPcreate.blade.php

```
<th colspan="6">Key Result Areas: <select class="btn btn-block btn-default">
                <option class="dropdown-header">Select Key Result Area</option>
                  @foreach($kras as $kras)
                  <option value="{{$kras->id}}">{{$kras->KRADetail}}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select></th>
```

and my route looked like this,

```
Route::get('/admin/{demopage?}', 'DemoController@demo')->name('demo');
route::resource('Kras','KrasController');
```

I'm a bit confused what to use in calling the blade file since its already declared in demopage. thats why i added the route for Kras, which is im not totaly sure. please help, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
   $kras=Kra::all();
   return view('admin.AIPcreate',compact('kras'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

Kra model code
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Kra extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['id',`KRADetail`];
    protected $table = 'table_name;

}
```

Krascontroller

```
public function index()
{
   $kras=Kra::all();
   return view('admin.AIPcreate',compact('kras'));
}
```

admin/AIPcreate.blade.php

```
<th colspan="6">  Key Result Areas: 
    <select class="btn btn-block btn-default">
            <option class="dropdown-header">Select Key Result Area</option>
            @foreach($kras as $kra)
                <option value="{{$kra->id}}">{{$kra->KRADetail}}</option>
            @endforeach
    </select>
</th>
```

Because your both variable name is same so it consider it as multiple values.

Here you are mistakenly take `Kras` instead of `Kra`. Check your model class name.

Comment: thank you for the response. however, i still have the same error.

Comment: _ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: kra (View: C:\Users\ICTOffice\Desktop\sbmMea\resources\views\admin\AIPcreate.blade.php)_

Comment: `dd` in your `index` method, check you are getting collection or not

Comment: I' not getting any collections.

_ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: kras (View: C:\Users\ICTOffice\Desktop\sbmMea\resources\views\admin\AIPcreate.blade.php)_

Comment: `public function index()
    {
        $kras=Kras::all();dd($kras);
        return view('admin.AIPcreate',compact('kras'));
    }` try this

Comment: define your table name in your model and then try

Answer (score 0):

try sending the data like below:

```
public function index()
{
    $kras=Kras::all();
    return view('admin.AIPcreate',['kras'=>$kras]);
}
```

and in foreach loop :

```
@foreach($kras as $kra)
   <option value="{{$kra->id}}">{{$kra->KRADetail}}</option>
```

@endforeach

Comment: its not working.
I tried this code, but i receive this
_ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: kras (View: C:\Users\ICTOffice\Desktop\sbmMea\resources\views\admin\AIPcreate.blade.php)_